# displaying JSON data more clear in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json data like

```
{"Player1": {"inventory": {"tas-count": 5, "kiriktas-count": 0, "odun-count": 0}}}
```

But it seems too complex. I want to edit, change it like

```
{
  "Player1": {
    "inventory": {
      "tas-count": 5,
      "kiriktas-count": 0,
      "odun-count": 0,
    }
  }
}
```

I looked for it but there is nothing on Stackoverflow and also things like "\n" are not working. I heard that in other languages, there are libraries for making a clear json data. Might there are some like this in Python.

Comment: or maybe just `pprint.pprint(data)`? [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
{
    "4": 5,
    "6": 7
}
```

You can check out pretty printing here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
import json
data = {"Player1": {"inventory": {"tas-count": 5, "kiriktas-count": 0, "odun-count": 0}}}

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Output:

```
{
    "Player1": {
        "inventory": {
            "kiriktas-count": 0,
            "odun-count": 0,
            "tas-count": 5
        }
    }
}
```